# How to use a textbox to input multiple HEX values into an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, hex, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to use a textbox control so the user can input Hex values into it, press enter and it is stored in an array. Then enter another hex value press enter and it is stored in the array.

I'm new to programming, so maybe there is a more suitable control than textbox to do this?

This is the code I've come up with so far, I'm not sure how you would clear the textbox when the user presses enter though, maybe there is something more suitable to input the values?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
    private void Test_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string hexString = Test.Text;
        int num = Int32.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        int[] arr = new int[20];

        for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            arr[i] = num;
            ReadValue.Text = num.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: It must be an array or it could be any non-fixed size collection?

Comment: It can be any non fixed size collection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `NumericUpDown` control and set its `Hexadecimal` property to `true`.
Than you can use his KeyDown event

```
private List<int> hexValues = new List<int>();

private void numericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        hexValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value));

        // Reset the value.
        numericUpDown1.Value = Decimal.Zero;
    }
}
```

Then if you need the array:

```
int[] hexValuesArray = hexValues.ToArray();
```

Comment: would this work if the user were to type in the values instead of using the up/down arrows?

Comment: @Brendan Of course! If you use a TextBox you would have to filter the input characters, with the NumericUpDown control you don't need to.